# Find memory leak with perfview

Tags: c#, memory, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, perfview

I have a C# (.net 4.5) service in production which is compiled in debug. 
In one day it has leaked 900mb of memory. 
Actually uses 10gb of memory.

So I tried to make a diff with perfview, but I can't find my 900mb leaking.

What I can see is the unreachable memory has been increased about 1000mb. 
What does this mean?

So basically, I think there isn't a real memory leak. Maybe the GC is not working, as I expect.

[image: perfview diff]

[image: perfmon]

What can I do to find what it causing to incrase the memory consumption by 400mb-900mb per day?

Comment: I can see a lot of things on the large object heap - I'd start by finding out what they are and if there's a way of avoiding them. Then find out what's living to the 2nd gen  they may well stay around for a very long time. Do you have some large xml?

Comment: It processed 23400 xml files with an avg of 5kb per file. There are 200 xml files between 50kb and 600kb.

Answer (score 2):

> Find memory leak with perfview

PerfView is a performance-analysis tool that helps isolate CPU- and memory-related performance issues.

> What can I do to find what it causing to incrase the memory
>   consumption by 400mb-900mb per day?

1. Install a good memory profiler tool Eg: [ANTS Memory Profiler](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/), which comes with 14 day trial.
2. Run the application by starting a profile session and check what instances are growing continuously.

[This walkthrough](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/walkthrough) covers everything you need to do. There is no big learning curve.